# Mocking request object with Jasmine and Express

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, jasmine, mocking

I have a very simple method:

```
module.exports = {
  login: function (username, password, req, res) {
    authModule.check_login({login: username, pass: password}).then(function (user) {
      req.session.regenerate(function () {
        req.session.user = username
        req.session.userID = user.id
        req.session.fullName = user.fullName
        req.session.email = user.email

        res.redirect('/user')
      })
    }).catch(function (err) {
      res.render('login', {
        unsuccessful: true
      })
    })
  }
}
```

In my unit tests I'm trying to verify that this method actually sets the session vars correctly. I've been trying to mock the request object by using `jasmine.createSpy`, but it doesn't seem to work, for example:

```
describe('user_login.login', function () {
  it('sets the session vars', function (done) {
    let req = jasmine.createSpy('req')
    const res = {
      render: function (renderTemplate, renderValues) {
        let template = renderTemplate
        let values = renderValues
      }
    }
    const userLogin = require('../helpers/user_login')
    userLogin.login(process.env.USER, process.env.PASSWORD, req, res)
    expect(req.session.regenerate).toHaveBeenCalled()
    done()
  })
})
```

returns:

```
Failures:
1) user_login.login sets the session vars
  Message:
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'regenerate' of undefined
```

Is there any way for me to get access to the session variables without making a request to the server? I'm trying to test the function itself, and not the server. What is the correct way of mocking the request object?

Thank you for you time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've figured it out, thanks to @ShabbY's help:

```
describe('user_login.login', function () {
  it('sets the session vars', function (done) {
    let req = {
      session: {
        regenerate: function (fn) {
          return fn()
        }
      }
    }

    const res = {
      render: function (renderTemplate, renderValues) {
        let template = renderTemplate
        let values = renderValues
      }
    }
    const userLogin = require('../helpers/user_login')
    spyOn(req.session, 'regenerate').and.callThrough()
    userLogin.login(process.env.USER, process.env.PASSWORD, req, res)
    .then(function () {
      expect(req.session.user).toBe('myUser')
      done()
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

hmm.. you are currently creating a spy for the request object. but you actually want to spy on req.session.regenerate function.

try to replace your mocked req with the following:

```
let req = {session: {regenerate: jasmine.createSpy('regenerate')}};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, the test still fails ("Expected spy regenerate to have been called").

Comment: I think the issue is that what I really want to spy on is `regenerate`'s callback, rather than `regenerate` itself. However I'm still struggling to understand how to do that...

Comment: okay, but now the tests fails with the expected error message at least :)

Comment: okay, but now the tests fails with the expected error message at least :)
there are some other issues:
1. your login function does not return the promise. therefore you cannot use it within your test. so change the beginning of your login function to `return authModule.check_login(....`

2. then in your tests, change the actual test and assertion to: `
userLogin.login(process.env.USER, process.env.PASSWORD, req, res).then(function() { expect(req.session.regenerate).toHaveBeenCalled();
done();
})
    `

Comment: the problem is, your login function is async. but your test executes syncronous. so you test if the function is called, before it actually gets called. therefore you need to return the promise from your login method in order to wait within your tests (or any other function that waits until the login has finished)

Comment: Yes, you're right, and your explanation makes perfect sense. In fact, the test now succeeds, so thank you very much for that. However, I'm trying to get to the `req.session.user`, `req.session.fullName`, and `req.session.email` variables, and that is why I mentioned that what I'm looking for is perhaps a spy on the `regenerate` callback function... or am I missing something stupid again?